# how to refer ReplicaSet in deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, devops, minikube

I am new to kubernetes and trying to create a deployment. So first I created a replicaset named rs.yml shown below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: ReplicaSet 
metadata:    
  name: web   
  labels:   
    env: dev    
    role: web 
spec:   
  replicas: 4   
  selector:      
    matchLabels:
      role: web   
  template:     
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: web   
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
```

and applied it using

> kubectl apply -f rs.yml

now Instead rewriting all this in deployment. I just want to refer this 'rs.yml' file or service inside my deployment.yml file.

Comment: You do not need to write `ReplicaSet` and `Deployment` just change the `Kind` to  `Deployment`. 
Applying the `Deployment` will automaticaly create the `ReplicaSet` and the `Pods`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create single YAMl file and add both thing deployment service inside it.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: ReplicaSet 
metadata:    
  name: web   
  labels:   
    env: dev    
    role: web 
spec:   
  replicas: 4   
  selector:      
    matchLabels:
      role: web   
  template:     
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: web   
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

you can divide the things using the `---` make the single YAML file.

also, another suggestion don't use the **Replicasets** by default **Deployment** create the **Replicaset** in the background.

You can use the **kind: deployment** can check `kubectl get rc` still replica set will be there. Deployment creates it in the background and manage it.

Comment: Still is there any way I can just refer or use replicaset inside deployment. Referencing file or replicaset object created by apply both will be fine. and also what about when the size of deployment.yml gets too big.

Comment: you cannot refer the one YAML from another yaml it don't support anything like import or include. You have to merge files only. if you have multiple YAML and you want to manage it better way and flow you can use the Kustomize. https://kustomize.io/

Comment: `deployment.yaml` file won't get big in GB or MB as YAML is very lightweight. just merge the file use the `kind:deployment` and apply the file your pods will be up and running.

Comment: To extend @HarshManvar answer - you can have multiple yaml files, separate for deployment, service, configmaps etc. and apply them all at once with `kubectl apply -f .`  (note the . at the end) - just put them in a separate directory to separete them from other manifests.